# What exactly is the effect of "Archiving" a conversation in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

Aside from the obvious (the line item for the conversation disappears from active chats and appears in the list of Archived Hangouts), **what exactly are the effects of "Archiving" a conversation in Google Hangouts?**

(in particular, i'd like to know the effect on synching with Hangouts on Android; but any other effects as well)

Answer (score 1):

It de-clutters your chat list. The conversation remains in your archived conversation list though and is available at hangouts.google.com (although it's a little hidden) and in the "Archived" section of the Android app.

Presumably if you add to an archived conversation it will become "unarchived" (as it's active again).

Otherwise, I don't see that anything else happens.

Comment: The question was explicitly if anything **other** than what you said happens under the covers

Comment: @DVK: Only Google can _really_ say what happens "under the covers", but from what I've seen in the (very scant) documentation and my own experimentation, this is all there is.